# Is it possible to use Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition to write an Excel Plugin?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, excel-2003

I have this question because I am not familiar latest generation of MS VS product.

But for work reason I may need to develop an Excel plugin for Excel 2003. I would like to study what are the alternative (other than using VBA)

I have a VS C++ 2008 Exp Edition installed. From the available project types, I don't think I can create a xll like program in it. Is it correct?

It is not necessary to use C/C++. VB or C# are fine as long as they can get the job done.

If there is any relevant example for this development env, please kindly provide a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [XLW](http://xlw.sourceforge.net/) a wrapper for the Excel API

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything that compiles code to write an Excel plugin for Excel... as long as you conform the the API for Excel plugins.